# Means to use Color Swatch in settings?

Tags: ios, application-settings

I'd hoped to find that someone's worked out a means to provide a choice of colors from the application settings (even with InAppSettings) with some kind of view of the (graphical) color swatch itself. My fallback implementation is a settings child pane of text multi-values of a small set of colors obviously without any swatch (unless there's a way of using icon.pngs therein).

Is someone aware such an implementation?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no approved way to do what you ask besides RGB values, and even then it's not user friendly.  I can recommend two projects if you would like to provide a pallet in-app though:

[IL Color Picker](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/il-color-picker) is simply excellent. I cannot recommend it highly enough.  It's intuitive, and unique, and it looks like photoshop's implementation.

[Color Picker](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ancolorpicker) a control styled like a nib's default color pallet.